# Nullspace of a product is a subspace of the first matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ and $B \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Assume $p<n$, rank$(A)=p$, and $B$ is invertible.

What additional assumptions are required on $B$ to make null$(AB)\subseteq$ null(A)?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I wanted to start by checking the case when B is diagonal. By checking some little problems I can see that diagonal matrices don't always work.

Comment: Ok, good. When do diagonal matrices stop working? What do they have in common?